# PHP curl broken in 5.6 vs 5.4 (Centos7)

Tags: php, centos7, curl

I run a simple php script using curl on Centos7 like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://1.2.3.4:80/hello");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_errno($ch));
```

This works perfectly in an instance using PHP 5.4. I had to upgrade to PHP 5.6 and mysteriously this stopped working, giving me `CURLE_FAILED_INIT`.

`phpinfo()` of the two versions don't seem to show differences between curls (5.4 and then 5.6)

[image: 5.4] [image: 5.6]

both instances have `Additional .ini files parsed` which both list a `curl.ini` which is equal in both cases:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Anyone has any pointer on how to troubleshoot? If I bring up the 5.4 instance this immediately works; switch back and broken again.

Also, there are no relevant logs (debug level).

Installation info:

```
# yum install rh-php56
# yum install rh-php56-php-curl
... rh-php56-php-common-5.6.25-1.el7.x86_64 is installed and updated 
# yum list rh-php56\*
rh-php56.x86_64                       2.3-1.el7    
rh-php56-php.x86_64                   5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-bcmath.x86_64            5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-cli.x86_64               5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-common.x86_64            5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-dba.x86_64               5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-devel.x86_64             5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-embedded.x86_64          5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-enchant.x86_64           5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-gd.x86_64                5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-gmp.x86_64               5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-intl.x86_64              5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-ldap.x86_64              5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64          5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-mysqlnd.x86_64           5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-odbc.x86_64              5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-opcache.x86_64           5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-pdo.x86_64               5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-pear.noarch              1:1.9.5-4.el7
rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64        1.3.6-3.el7  
rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64  1.3.6-3.el7  
rh-php56-php-pecl-memcache.x86_64     3.0.8-12.el7 
rh-php56-php-pecl-mongo.x86_64        1.5.8-3.el7  
rh-php56-php-process.x86_64           5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-pspell.x86_64            5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-recode.x86_64            5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-snmp.x86_64              5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-soap.x86_64              5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-xml.x86_64               5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-php-xmlrpc.x86_64            5.6.25-1.el7 
rh-php56-runtime.x86_64               2.3-1.el7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade to 5.6? Are you sure that's desired? http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Well, that's what my env provides! Can't do anything about that. Still this is driving us crazy. Still haven't found the reason for this crazy behavior.

Comment: @JoeSlav: I'm not so much into system configuration, but I would guess on first sight this is probably because of an underlying libcurl? From what I know the package manager could deal with that but I'm not so much into CentOS I must admit. I know I got on a Centos6 with the remi repositories PHP 5.6 working, and that was an upgrade, too (and with curl), I didn't had such problems. See as well my comment on the other question.

Comment: Agree with @hakre, see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLEFAILEDINIT